# Can I create a local ubuntu user from live USB?

Tags: ubuntu, liveusb

Is there a way to create a user on the local system (running Ubuntu) when the system has been booted with a live USB? All drives are read/write accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the system drives under e.g. `/mnt/local`, then perform a chroot into that directory. You will be able to manipulate it almost as if you were running it directly.